# WP7 getting device coordinates

Tags: windows-phone-7

I try to get my device coordinates using google maps api by http request, I need an api key but I can not take api key. Are there not api key available for windows phone application?And how can I take my device coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GeoCoordinateWatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808838.aspx)  class available in `WP7` to get device coordinates by GPS or WiFi/Cell towers. Also, you can choose desired accuracy / battery consumption to satisfy your needs.